# Displaying ticks on top of gauge chart

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to create a gauge chart with the ticks rendered *on top* of the bar. Ideally, it would look something like this:

[image: Goal]

However, I haven't been able to find a setting to change their render order. Right now, my chart looks like this:

[image: Current]

Is there a way to change the rendering order of the ticks and the bar in Highcharts' gauge charts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the examples provided by highcharts, i'm able to create a gauge where the ticks are rendered above the gauge bar. It has to do with the `zIndex` property of the yAxis. Using the template provided by highcharts, in the gaugeOptions object, set the `yAxis`:`zIndex` property to `100`. Then in the actual gague config/data object, set teh `yAxis`:`zIndez` to `99`. When you do this, the ticks will continue to appear over the bar even as it passes the ticks value. Take a look at the highcharts updated jsFiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/3tsrxfq5/1/**

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the help.